# How to send a file using xmodem protocol from the command line

Tags: modem

I have a scope attached to RX and TX lines of the serial port. If I do:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0
```

I get a steady stream of 'C' characters so the remote side is up and sending.
If I do:

```
cat {filename} > /dev/ttyS0
```

I get a burst on TX line w/o any protocol. If I do the following:

```
/usr/bin/sx -vv -k -X -b -c send {filename}
```

TX line remains inactive. File is binary and expecting xmodem 1K protocol. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should write that as answer below in 6 hours ;).

Comment: Glad he knew because I haven't used the protocol in 25 years. Thanks for the memories.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, given by the now-inactive OP, was:

```
sx {filename} > /dev/ttyS0 < /dev/ttyS0
```

Comment: Is that the name of a command...?

Comment: I don't know! I pulled it from the OP's question (where they appeared to self-answer it).

Comment: next, we'll get a gopher question.

Comment: I don't understand this answer... What is that?

Answer (score 1):

For others using embedded systems who might still want/need to send a file via XMODEM, this method works well with a Raspberry Pi or similar system:
Install sx and ser2net

Add a line in the **/etc/ser2net.conf** file for the TTY connected to the UART and set the correct baud rate (115200 in this example):

```
5000:raw:115200:/dev/ttyUSB0:115200 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT
```

Use sx to load the file:

```
sx -vv -X -b --tcp-client localhost:5000 embedded-image.bin
```

Comment: Where do you get `rx/sx` these days? I can't find the sources.

Comment: If you're using a Debian system you can get it with the lrzsz package, or you can get the sources here: https://www.ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html